# How to synchronize table updates

Tags: mysql, database, cgi

I've single database table containing some financial information. Multiple users may be viewing and updating at the same time from a web form on their computers.

What I want is that anyone who does an update must be doing based on latest table contents. I mean two people may click update at the same time. Say first person's update is successful. Now the second person's update is based on stale information and did not get chance to see the latest update from the first person.

How to avoid such situation?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the isolation level of your database server to REPEATABLE READ at least. When it's used, the dirty reads and nonrepeatable reads cannot occur. It means that locks will be placed on all data that is used in a query, and another transactions cannot update the data.

Comment: I think my question is different